# Cannot find symbol in java swing

Tags: java

I am getting compile-time error saying cannot find symbol `j.setDefaultCloseOperation`

```
symbol: variable EXIT_ON_CLOSE
location: class Test
```

Below is my program.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame j=new JFrame();
        j.setSize(900,900);
        j.setVisible(true); 
        j.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

I have searched the web but not able to find correct answer, please help me.

Comment: Because EXIT_ON_CLOSE is a constant.  What are you trying to refer it to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` is defined as a static final int in `JFrame` class. If you want to use that, you can do one of the following

1. `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` i.e, `j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`
2. Use a static import `import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;` or `import static javax.swing.JFrame.*;` (In this case, your existing code will work).

There is also one defined in `WindowConstants` too. (`WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`)

IMO, the first option is better as the readers can see exactly from where `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` comes from (without needing to hover the mouse over it in an IDE or going to the imports section to find that out).

Comment: @HoneyYadav I have updated the answer. When you extend from it you get the static int from it

Comment: You should not implement an interface just to get convenient access to its fields. You also wouldn't derive your living room from your car just to get access to the sunglasses you left in the glove box. Would you? ;-)

Comment: You mean to say that simply importing class doesn't import its static final variables

Comment: @Honey Yes. You need a *static import*